# Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. When i try to delete memberof properties from disabled users

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

We have a lot of disabled users, I want to write a script to delete the `memberof` property and keep the default (domain user). The `.csv` file I'm importing has a list of 5 `samaccountname` for testing purpose. when I execute this script I get this error message.
I do not get this message when I run the script for individual users but when I import the `.csv` file with the list of users I receive this error. Thanks for the help in advance.

```
c:\user\..\Desktop> .\powerAD.ps1
```

> Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The
>   argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try
>   the command again.

This is the script I wrote:
This there something wrong with my syntax??

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

ForEach ($user in (import-csv -path "C:\users\j\desktop\ADUSER1.csv"))

{
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $user.samaccountname |
% {Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $user.samaccountname -MemberOf -confirm:$false $_}
}
```

.csv file is in this format.

```
jbry
pbarb
dvan
```

[Screenshot from excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLIHm.png)

Comment: What does the .csv file look like? What happens if you change the body of the `foreach` loop to read 

`Write-Host $user.samaccountname`

?

Comment: .csv just has list of names

Comment: Please paste a copy of the CSV into your question; a proper CSV will have more than that in it. You can redact the actual names or account ids into bogus ones that follow your conventions.

Comment: like first intial last name ex. jthomas

Comment: We need the file. That information is not helpful. Specifically the headers and a couple of rows. If PowerShell thinks there is something wrong with your source data we cannot guess what that is.

Comment: You also have an error with your remove-call. It should be `Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $user.samaccountname -MemberOf $_ -Confirm:$false`

Comment: sorry for the delay guys im dragging and dropping the file but it is not uploading. can i send snippet of the file. or you can instruct me ?

Comment: Copy and paste the text in an [edit] to your question. If it formats wrong we can try to fix it. Hopefully the issue is not hidden in pasting the text here.

Comment: i have uploaded the image of the file and uploaded the text file.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin  I get this when i updated the script with ForEach ($user in (import-csv -path "C:\users\jxavier\desktop\ADUSER1.csv"))
{
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership Write-Host $user.samaccountname |
% {Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $user.samaccountname -MemberOf $_ -confirm:$false}

}A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts
argument '$null'.
At C:\Users\jxavier\Desktop\powerAD.ps1:5 char:1
+ Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership Write-Host $user.samaccountname |

Comment: Try ForEach ($User in (Import-CSV -Path "C\Users\JXavier\Desktop\ADUSER1.CSV")) { Write-Host $user.sAMAccountName } and report what it prints.

Comment: Like this??: ForEach ($user in (import-csv -path "C:\users\jxavier\desktop\ADUSER1.csv"))
{
Write-Host $user.sAMAccountName  |
% {Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $user.samaccountname -MemberOf $_ -confirm:$false}

}

Comment: @JeffZeitlin When i execute the ps1 script it doesnt do anything..

Comment: @user7526407 - No, use **exactly** the script I gave you. `Write-Host` does not leave anything in the pipe. The script I provided is for diagnostic purposes. Our repeated requests for the exact CSV file is also for diagnostic and analysis purposes. Without this information, we will not be able to help you, and if we keep on having to fight you for the information we need to help you, we will simply stop working on the question.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin it doesnt do anything.. PS C:\Users\jxavier\Desktop> ForEach ($User in (Import-CSV -Path "C:\Users\JXavier\Desktop\ADUSER1.CSV")) { Write-Host $user.sAMAccountName }
PS C:\Users\jxavier\Desktop>

Comment: it site does not allow me to upload bc im beginner..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your csv file. You are calling for the `samaccountname` property from it, but no column has that as the column header. Either read it in as a text file with `Get-Content` or give it a header.

```
ForEach ($user in (Get-Content "C:\users\j\desktop\ADUSER1.csv")) {
    Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $user | 
        ? {$_.Name -ne "Domain Users"} |
        % {Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $user -MemberOf $_}
}
```

Comment: what is the purpose of ? {$_.Name -ne "Domain Users"} |

Comment: Not even sure if you can remove a user from `Domain Users`, but the question specifically asked not to remove that group membership. Quoted: _I want to write a script to delete the memberof property and keep the default (domain user)._

Comment: i think it shouldnt delete the domain user memberof because domain user is the default.

Comment: Agreed, as I already stated I don't think you can remove them from their primary group. But why run a command that tries to do just that when you can filter it out?

Comment: It works perfectly now. thank you. is there a way i can write the script to only check "Disabled Users" OU specifically ??. some users may have the same first initial last name ex. bsmith, there may be 3 bsmith but only 1 bsmith is a disabled user.. any suggestions i can do??

Comment: `samaccountname` has to be unique. But you could use `Get-ADuser -scope` (In fact you could use that to get the `memberof` property rather than `ADPrincipalGroupMembership`).

Comment: If an answer worked for you, then it is best practice to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments above and your linked image from Excel, BenH is probably correct. What you need to do now is convert your names, which are `string`s in PowerShell, into `ADUser` objects to pass as the `-Identity` parameter to `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` and `Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership`:

```
foreach ($user in (Import-CSV -Path "C:\users\j\desktop\ADUSER1.csv"))
{
    $u = Get-ADUser -Filter 'sAMAccountName -eq $user'
    $u | Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership |
          Where-Object {$_.name -ne "Domain Users"} |
          ForEach-Object {Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $u -MemberOf $_}
}
```

Comment: `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` takes SAM Account Names for `identity`. So the `Get-ADUser` isn't necessary. And if you are using `Get-ADUser` then you could just use `memberof` and skip `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership`

Comment: @BenH - When I've passed strings representing sAMAccountNames to cmdlets requiring an "identity", the cmdlet has "choked" as often as not; because I haven't figured out why, I added the step that I know will ensure that the identity is accepted. You're right about using `.memberof` instead of dancing with `*-ADPrincipalGroupMembership`, though; that was just plain incomplete thinking on my part.